# What happens in the area between two black holes before they collide?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

Before two black holes collide, the area between them must be under incredible stress.  The effect could be measured by measuring the radiation from some object behind them.

Comment: This site has some relevant links, and a couple of pretty diagrams: https://www.cardiff.ac.uk/physics-astronomy/research/research-groups/gravitational-physics/research-areas/binary-black-hole-modelling

Comment: related question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/31989/

Comment: Kip Thorne heads a visualization initiative in which the results of numerical simulations of black hole mergers are stunningly portrayed in video animations. The results of his group's work are accessible on-line and are very impressive.

Comment: The answers I've gotten so far are about just the black holes.  What I'm asking about is the area between them.  Imagine stars, planets, gases, protons, electrons, etc., between the two black holes; what's the effect on them?  For example: can measurements in that area be used to generate real numbers about spaghettification?